# NoReverseMatch at /account/login/ (Trying to use Class based authentication views)

Tags: django, django-authentication

I am trying to use Django's class based authentication views and am getting the following error when attempting to access the login view:

```
NoReverseMatch at /account/login/
Reverse for 'register' not found. 'register' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Error during template rendering

In template /Users/justin/Desktop/Programming/Python/django_book/social/website/account/templates/base.html, error at line 0
```

All authentication templates are stored at `account/templates/registration/` and dashboard.html  is stored at `account/templates/account/`, here is the code:

account/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.dashboard, name = 'dashboard'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name = 'login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name = 'logout'),
]
```

login.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Log-in{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Log-in</h1>
  {% if form.errors %}
    <p>
      Your username and password didn't match.
      Please try again.
    </p>
  {% else %}
    <p>Please, use the following form to log-in. If you don't have an account <a href="{% url "register" %}">register here</a></p>
  {% endif %}
  <div class="login-form">
    <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
      {{ form.as_p }}
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
      <p><input type="submit" value="Log-in"></p>
    </form>
  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

base.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{% block title%}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/base.css'  %}">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <span class = 'logo'>Bookmarks</span>
      {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <ul class = 'menu'>
          <li {% if section == "dashboard" %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
            <a href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">My dashboard</a>
          </li>
          <li {% if section == "images" %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
            <a href="#">Images</a>
          </li>
          <li {% if section == "people" %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
            <a href="#">People</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
        <span class = 'user'>
          {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            Hello {{ request.user.first_name }},
            <a href = "{% url 'logout'%}">Logout</a>
          {% else %}
            <a href = "{% url 'login'%}">Login</a>
          {% endif %}
        </span>
    </div>



    <div id="content">
      {% block content %}

      {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note sure if this is needed but the account/views.py with the `dashboard` view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request,
                  'account/dashboard.html',
                  {'section': 'dashboard'})
```

and dashboard.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Dashboard{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Dashboard</h1>
  <p>Welcome to your dashboard.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

I am following the book 'Django 2 By Example' and at this point I believe I have directly copy and pasted the code from here (https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Django-2-by-Example/tree/master/Chapter04) to try and fix this error, but I am still getting. I should note that I am using Django 3.2.6 and am not sure if this is causing it. Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: It seems you don't have the [register view](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Django-2-by-Example/blob/master/Chapter04/bookmarks/account/views.py#L40) nor the [url](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Django-2-by-Example/blob/master/Chapter04/bookmarks/account/urls.py#L22) required, that's why you are getting the error.

Comment: @bdbd I am not sure how long that would have taken me to realize, thank you. But do you know why it is saying the error is in line 0 of base.html?

Comment: That part I'm not sure. But this line `{% url "register" %}` is the likeliest cause based on the error message. It basically means it cannot find the url named `register` in your url patterns

Comment: Yes, i remove that and it worked with no problem. Have not yet set up the register view. Thanks.